# Javascript Scientific Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am not familiar with javascript. Is there any javascript library which implements a scientic calculator.

The scientic calculator should have all features of this sample [scientific calculator](http://www.uttool.com/live/scientific/scientificcalculator.aspx) . If not possible , part of features is also ok.

Comment: That is written in JavaScript only.. Have a look at their .js file and understand what they are doing.. If you face any problems let us run through your problems..

Comment: The link you provided is down. Also use google, there are lot of versions available online.

Answer (score 1):

The [built-in Math object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) probably has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

There avail lot of javascript directories which could give you the code for embedding the [scientific calculator](http://easycalculation.com/basic-scientific-calculator.php) to your website. Make use of those.